# How to move extension icon back to toolbar in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge

When you install an extension in Microsoft Edge, the icon appears in the toolbar. You can right-click that icon and select the option to "Move to the menu", which will remove the icon from the toolbar–great. Now how do you get it back? I can't for the life of me figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click the 3-dot on the top right of the browser.
2. You will see the extension icon(s). Right-click and select "Move to the toolbar".

[image: Edge menu]